# Search for an item in an n-ary tree

Tags: c, tree, tree-search

I have a tree n-ary composed in this way:

```
struct n_tree{
    struct list *adj;    
};

struct list{
    struct n_tree *child;
    struct list *next;
    int key;
};
```

How i can search an item?
I have implemented this function, but it does not work... Thanks!

```
struct list *find(struct list *root, int key){
    if(root){
        find(root->next,key);
        if (root != NULL){
            if(root->key == key){
                return root;
            }
            else if(root->child != NULL){
                return find(root->child->adj,key);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you split key ranges among `n` nodes?  I mean, with binary tree it's simple: everything below the `key` go to the left, and everything else goes on the right. But with `n` elements it's not so clear.

Comment: You make a recursive call `find(root->next,key);` but never use the result returned. Why do you make that call then?

Comment: You say you have a *'tree composed in this way'* but you actually don't show any *'way'*. You have just shown data structures, but did not explain their meaning: are lists sorted somehow? what is the relation between `key`s in a list linked with `next`? what is the relation between a `key` in a list item and those in `child` subtree?

Comment: because I need to use the return recursive calls to visit the tree.

Comment: the nodes are not sorted, a parent is composed of a list of children, the first node of the list is the first child of the parent

Comment: But your goal is to find a node with the given key, not 'to visit the tree'. You do that by scanning the tree, of course, but 1) you don't have to scan the whole tree – you can stop the scan as soon as you find what you need; 2) you need to return the node found – otherwise the recursive call is a pure waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are trying to implement is a n-ary tree with a binary implementation (first child, right sibling).

It's more obvious with other namings :

```
struct n_tree{
  struct list *root;    
};

struct tree_node{
    int key;
    struct tree_node *first_child;
    struct tree_node *right_sibling;
};
```

A recursive  search function returning the node with the key **key** or NULL if no node is found could be :

```
struct tree_node *find_node(struct tree_node *from, int key){
  // stop case
  if (from==NULL) return NULL;
  if (from->key==key) return from;
  // first we'll recurse on the siblings
  struct tree_node *found;
  if ( (found=find_node(from->right_sibling,key) != NULL ) return found;
  // if not found we recurse on the children
  return find_node(from->first_child, key);
}
```

If you need a wrapper function with a n_tree argument :

```
struct tree_node* find(struct n_tree* tree, int key) {
  return find_node(tree->root, key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Before* looking at the children, you need to look at the local node, since that's how you actually *find* things and end the recursion.

Also, doing a recursive call and ignoring the return value is pointless (unless there's an "out-parameter", which there isn't here). So don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is (possibly the smallest) modification of your code to achieve your goal:

```
struct list *find(struct list *root, int key){
    for(; root != NULL; root = root->next){   // scan the siblings' list
        if(root->key == key)                  // test the current node
            return root;                      // return it if the value found

        if(root->child != NULL) {             // scan a subtree
            struct list *result = find(root->child->adj, key);
            if(result)                        // the value found in a subtree
                return result;                // abandon scanning, return the node found
        }
    }
    return NULL;                              // key not found
}
```